# How do I format CouchDB design documents in a human readable way?

Tags: javascript, json, view, couchdb

Since `views` are defined with `JSON` in `CouchDB` I'm having a hard time defining those in a human readable fashion.

Take this document:

```
{
    "language": "javascript", 
    "views": {
        "by_location": {
            "map": "function(doc) { if (doc.location != null) emit(doc.location, doc) }" 
        }, 
        "by_location_tags": {
            "map": "function(doc) { if (doc.top_tags) { for(i=0;i<doc.top_tags.length;i++) { emit([doc.top_tags[i].tag_name, doc.location], doc); } } }"
        }
    }
}
```

Writing the map function as one long string is plain ugly and it's insanely hard to spot bugs. I wonder what is the workflow for defining views in `CouchDB`? I feel as I'm missing the obvious.

Comment: @Riku Funny that you reformatted the function into a human readable way. But this is actually incorrect as it's not valid JSON this way ;-)

Comment: I reformatted it since it's essential for this question to show the actual problem.

Comment: maybe seperating it into different strings and adding + sign would help ? For example 
`"function" +
"other part" +
"other part" ?`

Comment: What editor are you using to define them? Futon doesn't force you to type everything all as one line now does it?

Comment: Oh wow, I didn't know about `Futon`. Could you point that out as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to mentioned Futon, there are several tools that allow you to write your map and view functions with your favorite editors and save them on your local file system. Those tools than take care of "pushing" your code to CouchDB.

You can find [more about those tools here](http://couchapp.org/)